# android fragment replace fiil_parent with frame layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-framelayout

according to picture when i replace my fragment into FrameLayout the the size is not fit. for example my button in page is under the main layout object
[image]
activity_main layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.teskaco.bbpos.Activities.MainActivities.MainActivity">

    <com.alirezaafkar.toolbar.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/app_bar_top_padding"
        app:direction="rtl"
        app:font="@string/font_path"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/m_e_n_u"
        app:optionsMenu="@menu/main_menu">

        <com.teskaco.bbpos.CustumView.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/main_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/psp_name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorControlNormal"
            android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size" />
    </com.alirezaafkar.toolbar.Toolbar>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/buttonPanel"
        layout="@layout/main_top_bar" />


</LinearLayout>
```

my fragment layout xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_pay"
    tools:context="com.teskaco.bbpos.Activities.MainActivities.PayBillFragment">
    <com.teskaco.bbpos.CustumView.CustomButton
        android:id="@+id/send_button"
        style="@style/LightRaiseColorButtonRippleStyle"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_300sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/send_button"
        android:textColor="@color/disable_button"
        android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6sdp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/skech_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/skech_image"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_90sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_101sdp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ghabz" />

            <com.teskaco.bbpos.CustumView.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/ghabz_textview"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_250sdp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/skech_image"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_21sdp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/bill_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/mediume_text_size" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/name_layout"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_250sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/raduis_bg_edit_text"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <com.teskaco.bbpos.CustumView.CustomTextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/shenase_text_input_layout"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_210sdp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

                <com.teskaco.bbpos.CustumView.CustomEditText
                    android:id="@+id/id_bill"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_6sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_6sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:hint="@string/id_Bill_text"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_4sdp"
                    android:textColor="@color/green_blue"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/defult_text_size" />
            </com.teskaco.bbpos.CustumView.CustomTextInputLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_16sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_12sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/user_id" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/name_layout1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_250sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/raduis_bg_edit_text"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <com.teskaco.bbpos.CustumView.CustomTextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/payment_text_input_layout"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_210sdp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

                <com.teskaco.bbpos.CustumView.CustomEditText
                    android:id="@+id/id_payment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_6sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_6sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:hint="@string/id_payment_text"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_4sdp"
                    android:textColor="@color/green_blue"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/defult_text_size" />
            </com.teskaco.bbpos.CustumView.CustomTextInputLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_16sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_12sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/user_id" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <com.teskaco.bbpos.CustumView.CustomButton
            android:id="@+id/barcode_reader"
            style="@style/GrayRaiseColorButtonRippleStyle"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_250sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"

            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_24sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/barcode_reader_text"
            android:textColor="@color/disable_button"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

replace code

```
fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment,   PayBillFragment.newInstance()).addToBackStack("PayBill").commit();
```

Comment: fill_parent is deprecated, fill_parent and match_parent are exactly the same

Comment: @MichaelStoddart yeah. right. but i use math_parent and i have again this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Parent Layout as RelativeLayout and use RelativeLayout property.

```
    <com.alirezaafkar.toolbar.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/app_bar_top_padding"
        app:direction="rtl"
        app:font="@string/font_path"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/m_e_n_u"
        app:optionsMenu="@menu/main_menu">

        <com.teskaco.bbpos.CustumView.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/main_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/psp_name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorControlNormal"
            android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size" />
    </com.alirezaafkar.toolbar.Toolbar>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonPanel" />


    <include
        android:id="@+id/buttonPanel"
        layout="@layout/tab_bottom_menus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i do this. but again i have this problem